# Binding values to pass to a on:click callback (anchor tag)

Tags: svelte

I am building a sidebar component that updates the active link when clicking on one of the sidebar items. Therefore, I need to pass down the current sidebar item object to enable its active state.

Question: how do I pass values to a callback after an on:click event? Here is how I do it on regular javascript:

```
<script>
  const items = [
    {
      text: "Home",
      url: "/"
    },
    {
      text: "Workarea",
      url: "/workarea"
    },
    {
      text: "Notes",
      url: "/notes"
    },
    {
      text: "Conf",
      url: "/conf"
    }
  ];

function click(obj,e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var activeItem = obj.id
}
</script>

//HTML

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {#each items as item}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a 
            on:click={onItemClick}
            href={item.url}
            >{item.text}</a>
        </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have checked the API and tried to use the `bind:xxxx` directives without success.

I expect the code to be able to update the current active sidebar item after clicking on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `item` to your handler:

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {#each items as item}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <a 
          on:click={() => onItemClick(item)}
          href={item.url}
        >{item.text}</a>
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rich... Why didn't I think of that. I have spent too much time doing React I guess :D